# c# Generic Set<T> implementation to access objects by type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I'm working on a net Core WebApi project and implementing a Unit Of Work pattern to access records from the database.

Consider below class:

Unit of Work:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public IBooksRepository Books { get; }

    public ICatalogueRepository Catalogues { get; }
    
    ...
}
```

Api Controller:

```
public class StudentController: ApiController
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public StudentController(IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = UnitOfWork;
    }

    public IActionResult Get()
    {
       var books =   _unitOfWork.Books.GetAll();
        return Ok(books);
    }
}
```

}

Currently I'm retriving the records from the database using above method,
I would like to access the repository object something like this.

```
var books =   _unitOfWork.Set<IBooksRepository>.GetAll();
```

Similar to `Set<T>` method in EntityFramework DBContext claas and the purpose is to make the controller class generic and to perform the get operation in a generic way.

How can I implement like a `Set<T>` method which finds the repository object from the UnitOfWork class?

Comment: What will that buy you?

Comment: What I'm seeing, based on the prototype you wrote, is the need for an IoC Container.  IoC containers have the ability to match up an Interface with an appropriate Implementation.  Failing that, you could write a Factory method that switches through all of your interface types and `new`s up the correct class.

Comment: @RobertHarvey By doing this I can move the repetitive code on the controller to the base class

Comment: "_Similar to Set<T> method in EntityFramework DBContext claas_" - the `T` is `Set<T>()` of EF `DbContext` represents an entity, yours doesn't.

Comment: I downvoted because this is _yet another_ case of someone reimplementing something already provided for you by EF: https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/

Comment: Also, have you noticed that the functionality of the `DbContext` seem a like an `Unit of Work` implementation? That's because it is one.

Comment: I didn't notice EF was part of the tags. I thought this was for a custom repository wrapping access to something custom :) I'm almost thinking of removing my answer. Fully agree, DbContext is UnitOfWork, DbContext.Set<T> is already Repository

Comment: It's a long debate to use Repository and Unit of Work pattern on top of Entity Framework. I have seen many benefits implementing it when you design an enterprise level frameworks. The Microsoft guide to implement repository and unit of work pattern using EF Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implementation-entity-framework-core

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the points of Robert Harvey. However, if you want to do this, a way to do it would be to refactor your code a bit and then use reflection:

You could refactor the code a bit:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public IRepository<Book> Books { get; }

    public IRepository<Catalogue> Catalogues { get; }

    public IRepository<T> Set<T>()
    {
        var allProperties = this.GetType().GetProperties();

        var property = allProperties.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(IRepository<T>) );
        return (IRepository<T>) property.GetValue(this);
    }
}
```

This is just a starter/idea, you can adapt it more to your context (optimizations, personal options, etc.).

PS: You wrote "similar to EF's `Set<T>`", but then did not use the "entity type" to get the repository in your code example. You can further simplify my example to checking for T and returning T instead of `IRepository<T>`:

```
public T Set<T>()
{
    var allProperties = this.GetType().GetProperties();

    var property = allProperties.SingleOrDefault(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(T) );
    return (T)property.GetValue(this);
}
```

However, this seems silly. I think there should be an `IRepository<T>` if you're going the "generic repository" route.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. There is a IRepository<T>.